# How can we create 3 VM's on a bare metal server using 2 NIC cards

Tags: linux-networking

I got this question in an interview that I need to create 3 VM's on a bare metal server but I have 2 NIC cards on the server.
My answer was may be we can share a NIC card with 2 VM's and 1 NIC card can be attached to the 3rd VM. I am not sure what I answered is right, but I am curious to know what would be the ideal answer here.

Can someone please explain.

Comment: An ideal answer would have *demonstrated that you already understand terminology & reasonable practices* and *how* the specifics of sharing the limited resource (here: NICs) affect ease of configuration, network topology, reliability, & latency. Specifically, your answer omits explicit consideration how the host itself is going to be managed after it assigns 2 out of 2 NICs exclusively to its virtual machines.

Comment: That is an nice example of an interview question that will demonstrate quite well what kind of technologies you’re already familiar with and what trade-offs and considerations you make. 
To me your answer demonstrated that you’re probably not an experienced sysadmin yet with regards to setting up virtualization. 

That’s ok. (Unless that was the role you were applying for.)

And in an interactive interview you could also have asked for clarification, for example would you haven able  to specify a particular network hookup for those NIC’s or are they already wired in a specific way?

Comment: As already commented, you didn’t consider remote management of the hypervisor. You therefore didn’t consider keeping that remote management traffic separate from the VM’s either.  

You didn’t consider a high-availability and/or high performance network setup that combines the two NIC’s. You didn’t consider logical network separation over that combined network uplink.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.